# Is this piecewise defined function in two variables lipschitz continuous?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, continuity, lipschitz-functions, piecewise-continuity

According to Picard–Lindelöf theorem, IVP
$$\begin{cases}y^\prime(t) = f(t,y(t))\\y(x_0)=y_0
\end{cases}$$
has a unique solution if $f$ is lipschitz continuous.
What if my ODE contain piecewise defined function $g:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$
\begin{equation}
g(x,y) = \begin{cases}
x^2\tanh(y)\text{ for } x>0\\
0 \text{ for } x\leq 0
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Is $g(x,y)$ lipschitz continuous in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (what is the $K$ then?) and if not, does it automatically mean, that ODE with such function has no solution?

**Edit.** I am curious about the situation like
$$
\mathbf{x}^\prime(t) = \mathbf
A^{n\times n}\mathbf{x}(t) +
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1(t)\\
x_2(t)\\
\vdots\\
g(x_1,x_2)\\
x_n(t)\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: You don't need Lipschitz continuity in $\Bbb R^2$ but Lipschitz continuity in the second variable ($y$).

Comment: Maybe I messed up my original question. Please see edit

Answer (score 0):

No, $g$ is not Lipschitz, as $x^2$ is not Lipschitz. But $g$ is Lipschitz on $(-\infty, r)\times\mathbb R$ for all $r$.

Thus the ODE has a solution on each such set, so it also has a solution on $\mathbb R$. Picard Lindelöf only needs local lipschitz, and that only in the second variable.

Comment: Maybe I messed up my original question. Please see edit